# Get trigger reason in build script

Tags: bamboo

Is there a way to see the type of trigger that caused a plan to run from a build script, maybe from an environment var?

#### Why

I'm doing a build that takes a fair amount of time to run a full build. I've put in a lot of effort to get incremental builds working. I've currently got bamboo setup to run incremental builds on the dev (master) branch, and full builds on the production branch, by setting up multiple plans.  I would like to do a full build on the dev branch scheduled once a day, but I want it to happen in the same plan as the incremental build that happens on code change.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to get the type of trigger, as no [variable](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-variables-289277087.html) is available as environment variable for your script.

However, you are the owner of the plans, and there *is* a variable telling you the name of the plan: `bamboo.shortPlanName` (actually also `bamboo.planKey`). Since you define the triggers of the plan, you should be able to infer the information on the trigger type from there.

> A Bamboo plan defines the details of your continuous integration
> workflow.  You use a plan to identify the source code repository,
> specify the tasks to run in your build, **and when to trigger a build**.
> Each plan belongs to a project.  You can add a plan to an existing
> project or create a new project.
> [source](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/getting-started-with-php-and-bamboo-289277284.html#:%7E:text=A%20Bamboo%20plan%20defines%20the%20details%20of%20your,an%20existing%20project%20or%20create%20a%20new%20project.)

Now, this probably won't help you with your goal, since, from what I understand, you'd like to change plan dynamically based on some condition. Your script might try to rely on external documents keeping track of what was the last plan being executed and decide what to do next based on the plan that has been triggered, but I'm stretching too far out.